# Change footnote number to text using tabu

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabu

**Problem:**

Changing footnote default numbering to text using the `tabu` package.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %colour tables
\usepackage{color, colortbl} % choose and define a colour
\usepackage{tabu} %for the font size of the tables
\usepackage{array}% tables
\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=2.7cm,rmargin=2.7cm]{geometry}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\definecolor{LightBlue}{rgb}{0.78,0.85,0.95}
\centering
\newcolumntype{A}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm} }
\newcolumntype{B}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm} }
\begin{tabu}{|p{4.5cm} B A A A A A|}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightBlue}    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Obs.} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Median} & \textbf{SD} & \textbf{Min} & \textbf{Max} \\
\hline
\footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

Changing the number 1 to bold text saying "Note."

Comment: you will find many peoples here don't recommend using tabu

Comment: @touhami In your experience, what is the recommended usage for tables?

Comment: what should the footnote say?

Comment: @musicman It should say "Note. The latest statistics can be found at http://" where "Note." Is in bold and the rest in normal font.

Comment: @kexxcream I don't really have experience. I use `booktabs, longtable, tabularx` and `multirow`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not stuck on `tabu`, this will work for a normal table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} % for footnotes in tables
\usepackage[tmargin=8in]{geometry} % only to push table toward footnote
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % to align table values and headers

\begin{document}

\footnote{A note.}Some text (before table).
{
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{Note}}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment = center, table-figures-integer=6, table-figures-decimal=1}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rSSSSSS} \toprule
{\bfseries{Variable}} & {\textbf{Obs.}} & {\textbf{Mean}} & {\textbf{Median}} & {\textbf{SD}} & {\textbf{Min}} & {\textbf{Max}} \\ \midrule
\tablefootnote{The latest statistics can be found at \ldots}A & 1.2 & 12.3 & 123.4 & 1234.5 & 12345.6 & 123456.7 \\
B & 123456.7 & 12345.6 & 1234.5 & 123.4 & 12.3 & 1.2 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
}
\footnote{Some other note.}Some other text (after table).
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the footnote as part of the table itself, that will be slightly different. For now, I assume you mean a normal footnote.